# Software to increase my volume on iPod nano 6th gen?

Tags: ipod, sound-volume, ear-phones

I have an iPod Nano 6th Generation and it had been working perfectly fine, but one day suddenly my up volume button got stuck. That button can't be pressed as it has gone down completely. I searched a lot and it seems to be a common problem that the buttons stuck and also I got a [useful link here](http://www.rbarrios.com/projects/NANO6BUTTON/) but I do not want to open up my ipod on my own.

Is there some way through software by which I can increase my volume?  I tried restoring my ipod but even that does not increase my volume to the full. I just want a software solution through which I can increase my volume up to the full. At the moment my volume is at mute so can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any software that can change the volume but you could use Apple Earphones with Remote to change the volume even though the buttons don't work.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB770G/B

I also found this, a remote that can be used with any headphones:

[iLuv Universal Headphone Remote For iPod](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16855992232)

Comment: I was more interested in the software if there is any.

Comment: I borrowed those headphones from my friend, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem also. I don't want to pay to repair it, as it will cost as much as a new iPod, since my warranty has run out.
I found a way to put your volume back to default (Middle. Halfway). Go to settings and select "Reset Settings". This won't delete anything on your iPod. However, if you are like me and increased the volume 100% in iTunes, make sure you take off your *before* playing music. :-) You can just change the volume settings in iTunes back to the normal volume.
I did this, and now I can set the volume back to the middle wuth just a simple reset settings. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open up your device and attempt a fix, here is a step by step guide with pictures...

http://www.rbarrios.com/projects/NANO6BUTTON/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Toying around with mine a little, I found that you should be able to reset the settings for your iPod and put the volume to half its maximum. It's in the Settings-Reset Settings option.

My volume "Up" is non-existent, but half is good enough for me. Just keep in mind that you'd need to reset anytime you went too low. Barring that, headphones with internal volume control are the way to go. Personally, I'm just going to stick with resetting until this iPod dies, then find a new MP3 player.